# Converted to Gradle, How to Create Branch on Existing Git Repository?

Tags: android, git, gradle, android-studio

I have used Android Studio to convert my existing project to Gradle.

These are the steps I took:

1. Connected Android Studio to my Git repository
2. Pulled the Git Repository into Android Studio into directory `git-project`
3. File > Import Project
4. Selected the project I had just pulled

Now I have a new directory named `gradle-project`

I want to add `gradle-project` as a new branch to my existing Git repository. When I open the `gradle-project`, I can create a new branch and commit to my local repository. If I try to push to my remote repository, it says "no remotes are defined".

Is it possible for me to add this as a new branch to my exiting remote repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must add the remote. Try to write in console: git remote add origin git://github.com/username/test.git

Here is the link https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote